# SwiftUI: Horizontally Align Views Inside a List

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to get items inside a list to line up in a specific way.

```
List {
    HStack {
        Text("1.")
        Text("Item 1")
    }

    HStack {
        Text("Item 2")
    }
}
```

That winds up looking like this:

```
1. Item 1
Item 2
```

What I'd *like* is to line up, in this example, "Item 1" and "Item 2":

```
1.  Item 1
    Item 2
```

That is, the "item" parts all line up whether they have a list marker or not, or if they have list markers of different lengths (number 1. lines up with 100.)

I tried [making a custom alignment guide as seen here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/how-to-create-a-custom-alignment-guide) but these don't seem to be respected inside a `List` --- it works fine if I make the `AlignmentGuide` and put it all in a `VStack`, but I need list behavior.

(I could fake this by getting rid of the `HStacks` and doing `Text("1.\tItem 1")` and `Text("\tItem 2")`. The tab stops would make everything line up, but I need to apply different formatting to the list marker and the list item (bolding, color, etc.), so they need to be discrete `Text` elements.)

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: It is really not about alignment, but about formatting cell content, as you would do in storyboard: have label for "1." and have label for "Item 1", and even if there is no number for "Item2", the label would be still there, empty... here is the same, just format cell correctly and in result you'll get correct "alignment".

Comment: This works fine if I want to explicitly tell the view how wide each of the initial `Text` frames should be. I'd prefer for the view to figure that out for itself but I might do this in the meantime.

Comment: Wrapping 2 HStack in 1 VStack(alignment: .trailing) does it work for you?

Comment: @EnesKaraosman They line up but inside one `List` row. They need to be in their own rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            HStack {
                Text("1.").frame(width: 20.0, height: nil, alignment: .leading)
                Text("Item 1")
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Item 2")
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 28, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
            }
            HStack {
                Text("2.").frame(width: 20.0, height: nil, alignment: .leading)
                Text("Item 3")
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Item 4")
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 28, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

** Updated **

Hope this is closer to what you are looking for.

By specifying a frame around the leading value, you can control its size so it should work for your need to modify the text value.

It should also be possible to calculate values for the purpose of setting the frame and padding, but these hard coded values should achieve the immediate effect.

Comment: This puts the whole HStack inside one list row, though.